# reads a single line of text from the user java

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

write a program that reads a single line of text from the user. This program should print "Too short" if the resulting string contains fewer than 10 characters; otherwise, it should print the number of characters in the string

heres what ive got so far,

```
package exercise;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex6 {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        ///creates a scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt the user to enter a line of text 
        System.out.print("Enter a line of text: " );
        String text = input.nextLine();

        //counts characters prints too short if text is less than 10 

        int counter = 0;
        for( int i=0; i < text.length(); i++ ) {
            if( text.charAt(i) == '$' ) { 
                counter++;
            }
                else if ( text.length() < 10){ 
                    System.out.println("To short"); 
            } 


            System.out.print("String Length :" );
            System.out.println(text.length());

        }
    }
}
```

the issue with this code is that if i type in man for example it would print out too short three times. output example below;

Enter a line of text: man
To short
String Length :3
To short
String Length :3
To short
String Length :3

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are looping through the length of the string. Thus, when entering a String with 4 characters, you loop through your condition 4 times, printing 4 times aswell.

```
public static void main(String[] args){


        ///creates a scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt the user to enter a line of text
        System.out.print("Enter a line of text: " );
        String text = input.nextLine();

        //counts characters prints too short if text is less than 10

        if (text.length() < 10) {
            System.out.println("Too short");
        } else {
            System.out.print("String Length :" );
            System.out.println(text.length());
        }
    }
```

You should avoid using a loop in this case. You only want to check it once.